# Which method do you suggest for my segmentation task post-processing step?

Tags: image-segmentation, edge-detection, post-processing

I am developing a neural framework for instance segmentation.

At the moment I have quite reasonable outcome (probability map) as follows:

**Input image:**

[image]

**Corresponding probability map:**

[image]

As you may noticed, the outcome has blurred boundaries while I asked the model to highlight DOG location.

My aim is to generate instance borders using:

**1:** *input image information.*

**2:** *associated probability map information.*

I'm thinking of *Graph cut Optimization* and *Max-Flow/Min-Cut* algorithm to extract instance boundaries.

But I wanted to know if you have a more recent exciting suggestion for me?

thanks,

Comment: Try a DoG filter ;-)

Comment: What method did you end up using?